# Non-minified Bluebird script for production environments

Tags: bluebird

According to [Bluebird's installation instructions](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/install.html) its non-minified [source](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.0.5/bluebird.js) has warnings and long stack traces not intended for production environments. Provided [production source](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.0.5/bluebird.min.js) is minified and from past experience adding already minified javascript to our minifying build process can cause problems later down the line.

Can I download a non-minified production code from somewhere? Can I build one myself?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was the case when you originally asked the question, but now there's both a minified and non-minified versions hosted

e.g.

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.5.0/bluebird.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.5.0/bluebird.min.js
```